# Load cell array from text file to Octave

Tags: octave

I have a text file containing output of Octave cell array:

```
confusionMatrix5 = 
{
  [1,1] =

     228     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
       0   113     0     0     0     0     0     1
      10     0    97     0     0     0     7     0
       1     0     2   225     0     0     0     0
       0     0     0     0   227     0     0     1
       0     2     0     0     0   112     0     0
       1     0     3     0     0     0   110     0
       0     1     0     0     0     0     0   227

  [2,1] =

     228     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
       0   113     0     0     0     0     0     1
       8     0    99     0     0     0     7     0
       2     0     1   225     0     0     0     0
       0     0     0     0   227     0     0     1
       0     1     0     0     0   113     0     0
       0     0     4     0     0     0   110     0
       0     1     0     0     0     0     0   227

   ...
}
```

I tried to simply copy the content of the file above and paste it but it throws bunch of errors, i.e.:

```
octave:105>   [3,3] =
parse error:

  invalid constant left hand side of assignment
```

Is there any way to easily load the cell array of such format back to the Octave cli?

---

Edit:  I managed to handle the situation with few regexes and text replacing this time but remember to save your workspaces, folks!

Comment: No, you can't just copy and paste the text like that. If you want to put variable data in a file, it would be better to use [`save`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/save.html) (and [`load`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/save.html)).

Comment: I know about `save` and `load` but it's kind of an emergency situation here since Octave crashed and I was left with the output only. The conclusion is that I'll have to use `save`&`load` more often in the future :)

Comment: Or better yet: write your code as scripts and run the scripts. Then you can always reproduce what you did and re-create your results.

Comment: I wonder if `load` uses the special filename `'-'` like `save` does. In the case of `save`, it prints the variable to a string...